# optional date field with simple_form

Tags: simple-form

I am using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to generate date input like so:

```
= f.input :date_of_death
```

However, it always pre-populates with the current date.

How can I have it come up "blank" and allow the user to easily NOT enter a date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to do this while still keeping the form split into dropdowns for Y/M/D.

```
= f.input :date_of_death, include_blank: true
```

Or if you want the first option to have text use prompt.

```
= f.input :date_of_death, prompt: "Choose Wisely"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way that I have found

f.input :date_of_death, as: :string

It will turn the input into a blank input field.  You will have to parse the string as a date in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use include_blank

```
= f.input :fecha_at, include_blank: true, start_year: Date.today.year - 90, end_year: Date.today.year
```